# HTML code in pre and xmp tags renders

Tags: jquery, html, google-code-prettify

I'm trying to display some HTML code in `<pre>` and `<xmp>` tags, but instead of just showing the code, this HTML code actually renders. Also I'm using Google Prettify to highlight the syntax.

```
<pre class="prettyprint code"></pre>
```

javascript

```
$(".code").html("<xmp>"+data+"</xmp>");
$('.prettyprinted').removeClass('prettyprinted');

prettyPrint();
```

So when I try to display `<b>HEllo</b>` I get **Hello**

Comment: Not reproduceable. The code, when augmented to a real example, works as intended. It is not clear why you are using *both* `pre` *and* `xmp`, since they are basically similar except for parsing: in `xmp`, no markup except the element’s own end tag is recognized – and this seems to be what you want.

Comment: I use pre because google prettify class needs it, and xmp because I found on internet that it will force code not to render. I don't have problems with code from other programming languages, just when I use HTML it renders

Comment: Same thing happends if I put only xmp tag. When I open chrome developer tools, in html, I can see my html tags as raw text, but in browser they are rendered

Comment: So? You are *supposed* to see tags in developer tools.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DJB0Wu2H This my problem, see the link. I noticed as soon as google prettify loads this problem occurs

Comment: You should clarify the question by editing the question itself. The code at the pastebin page is not the same as in the question.

Comment: Yeah I know, I added it manually so you can have a better view of what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I made `class="tag"` somewhere in my css, and apperently google prettify use same class name (`.tag`) to mark the html tags, so after I changed the name of my class to another name, everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTML-Entities.

e.g.

```
&lt;b&gt;HEllo&lt;/b&gt;
```

gets displayed as <b>HEllo</b>

Comment: Tried that, but instead getting < I get &lt